# How to center div with buttons (Bootstrap Responsive)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, resize, window-resize

HTML

```
<div id="panel">
   <form method="POST" action="">
     <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="veh_id">
       <option>1</option>
       <option>1</option>
       <option>1</option>
     </select>
     <input type="submit" value="GO" id="submit">
   </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#panel {
    position: absolute;
    left:32%;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: dashed 2px black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#submit {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 35px;
    width: 63px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#sel1 {
    min-width:425px;
    width:425px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The following div `panel` is on center with large screens but on mobile phones (Small screens) the whole div mix ups. I made my hard effort but didn't got success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using bootstrap and trying to center things, you shouldn't be pushing the elements around using left and what not. This can be very simply done using bootstrap helper classes

I'm not sure that this fits the bill 100% but should help. I stripped most of the provided css to make use of bootstrap,

a column that is 50% of the screen (centered) with something like

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3"></div>
```

and then styling buttons accordingly. I'm not sure why you have absolute on the wrapper, but if you need that it can still be used.

also you use both

```
display: block;
float: right;
```

which will cause the button to be rendered as a new line, but then you have a fixed width so it automatically goes right.

Hopefully this helps,

http://jsfiddle.net/1rLn0art/

Comment: That works . But how to place the drop down on map and make it transparent.

Comment: What do you want to make transparent? just the dropdown? you could add a rule to your css for select{background:transparent;} which would work. If you want this to be responsive, and you have a larger container, such as a map, add the bootstrap class to that element and then wrap this content inside of the bigger container. If you used something like "col-sm-12" on the map container, you could then drop this stuff inside and it should still be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

```
#panel {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: dashed 2px black;
    display: block;
    width:500px;
}
#submit {
    height: 35px;
    width: 63px;
}
#sel1 {
    min-width:425px;
    border: none;
}
```

Change your CSS to this.
You have many unrelated css here. You should go to MDN and find out what these css attributes means.

To center a div, `margin: 0 auto;` is an useful way. Set the div a `width`, make it `display: block. margin: 0 auto;`  clear all your float.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLjgXR